# jquery mobile and dynamic pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic

I have a simple html file which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Inpress</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/themes/inpress.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" /> 

    <script src="/src/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="/src/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/scripts/inpress/jquery.inpress.js"></script>  

    <style>
        * {
            -ms-touch-action: none;
        }

        .fullscreen {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

then I am creating all the pages dynamically using a combination of jquery and json.
My issue is that I can easily add the class **ui-page-active** to show the page, but it isn't working as I wish. 
In normal versions I can use the url with #home and it will show that, but when I refresh my page it always shows the first one.

So my question is:

Can I load all the items onto the page before jquery mobile tries to do it's magic?

**Update 1**

Ok, here is the code I use to create my pages.

```
function createPages(data) {
    if (data.configuration.global.target) {
        showDebug("Creating pages.");

        $.each(data.pages, function (i, item) {
            if (item.enabled) {
                var loadTemplate = (i == 0) ? true : false;
                createPage(item.template, loadTemplate);
            } else {
                showDebug("The page is disabled.");
            }
        });

        //if (document.location.hash != "")
        //    startPage = document.location.hash;

        //showDebug(startPage);

        //$.mobile.changePage(startPage);
    } else {
        showDebug("The target file could not be found.");
    }
};

function createPage(template, loadTemplate) {
    $.ajax({
        url: template,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            showDebug("Creating page.");

            var page = createElement(data);
            var id = page.attr('id');

            $('body').append(page);
            $('#' + id).trigger('create');

            showDebug("Page created: " + id);
        }
    });
};

function createElement(template) {
    var o;

    o = $('<' + template.element + '/>');

    if (template.id) {
        o.attr("id", template.id);
    }

    if (template.href) {
        o.attr("href", template.href);
    };

    if (template.src) {
        o.attr("src", template.src);
    };

    if (template.type) {
        o.attr("type", template.type);
    };

    if (template.classes) {
        $.each(template.classes, function (i, item) {
            o.addClass(item);
        });
    }

    if (template.data) {
        $.each(template.data, function (key, value) {
            $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                o.attr("data-" + key, value);
            });
        });
    }

    if (template.content) {
        $.each(template.content, function (i, item) {
            if (item.element) {
                o.append(createElement(item));
            } else {
                o.append(item);
            }
        });
    }

    return o;
};
```

and just so you get the idea of the json it is parsing:

```
{
   "id":"introPage",
   "element":"div",
   "data":[
      {
         "role":"page"
      }
   ],
   "content":[
      {
         "element":"div",
         "data":[
            {
               "role":"content"
            }
         ],
         "content":[
            {
               "id":"skip-intro",
               "element":"a",
               "href":"#homePage",
               "content":[
                  {
                     "id":"introMovie",
                     "element":"video",
                     "classes":[
                        "fullscreen"
                     ],
                     "content":[
                        {
                           "element":"source",
                           "type":"video/mp4",
                           "src":"/src/assets/test.mp4"
                        },
                        {
                           "element":"source",
                           "type":"video/webm",
                           "src":"/src/assets/test.webm"
                        },
                        {
                           "element":"source",
                           "type":"video/ogg",
                           "src":"/src/assets/test.ogv"
                        },
                        "Your browser does not support the video tag."
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I hope that helps you help me :)

cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: Why would want to inject elements before JQM enhance them? To create a page, call `pagecreate` not `create` for the active page only. For other pages injected into DOM, you don't need further enhancement.

Comment: not sure what you mean. from the looks of the documentation you only call pagecreate when you want to run a plugin on that page

Comment: `pagecreate` enhances the page and elements within. It's usually used when adding or modifying major parts of page i.e. header/footer/panel and only for the active page. Demos: panel http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/kCtnG/ pages http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/YJuJ5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this my self. 
The problem was with getting the code to execute at the right time. Looking at the documentation the best time to do this was http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/

so I modified my code and this is what I have:

```
debug = true;
initialized = false;

$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
    if (!initialized) {
        initialize();

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

function initialize() {
    $.getJSON('/src/assets/json/config.txt', function (data) {
        initialized = true;

        createPages(data);
    });
};

function createPages(data) {
    if (data.configuration.global.target) {
        showDebug("Creating pages.");

        $.each(data.pages, function (i, item) {
            if (item.enabled) {
                var loadTemplate = (i == 0) ? true : false;
                createPage(item.template, loadTemplate);
            } else {
                showDebug("The page is disabled.");
            }
        });
    } else {
        showDebug("The target file could not be found.");
    }
};

function createPage(template, loadTemplate) {
    $.ajax({
        url: template,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            showDebug("Creating page.");

            var page = createElement(data);
            var pageId = '#' + page.attr('id');

            $('body').append(page);

            if (document.location.hash) {
                if (document.location.hash == pageId) {
                    $.mobile.changePage(document.location.hash);
                }
            } else {
                if (loadTemplate) {
                    $.mobile.changePage(pageId, { changeHash: false });
                }
            }

            showDebug("Page created.");
        }
    });
};

function createElement(template) {
    var o;

    o = $('<' + template.element + '/>');

    if (template.id) {
        o.attr("id", template.id);
    }

    if (template.href) {
        o.attr("href", template.href);
    };

    if (template.src) {
        o.attr("src", template.src);
    };

    if (template.type) {
        o.attr("type", template.type);
    };
    if (template.classes) {
        $.each(template.classes, function (i, item) {
            o.addClass(item);
        });
    }

    if (template.data) {
        $.each(template.data, function (key, value) {
            $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                o.attr("data-" + key, value);
            });
        });
    }

    if (template.content) {
        $.each(template.content, function (i, item) {
            if (item.element) {
                o.append(createElement(item, false));
            } else {
                o.append(item);
            }
        });
    }

    return o;
};

function showDebug(message) {
    if (debug) {
        console.log(message);
    }
};
```

You can see on the **createPage** function that I run this bit of code:

```
if (document.location.hash) {
    if (document.location.hash == pageId) {
        $.mobile.changePage(document.location.hash);
    }
} else {
    if (loadTemplate) {
        $.mobile.changePage(pageId, { changeHash: false });
    }
}
```

that handles my hash if we have one set or if we don't, it checks to see if this is the page that should be loaded. This will basically set the first page as the default page (without changing the hash) but if we have specified a hash in the url then it will go there instead.

Answer (score 0):

The below code adds in the dynamic page(s) which have been defined as the JSON here.  I have left a holding page here which isn't strictly necessary but will look better if you're loading in templates over ajax as users might see empty space for a while otherwise.

Here the first page has a link you can click to load the dynamically generated page.  Naturally since you have relative urls the video will only display properly if the relative urls are correct.  I have changed the href of the video to go back to the `mainPage` here to demonstrate how the dynamic page can change to another page via anchor href. (it could also be the id of another dynamically added page).
If you want to load one of your dynamic pages almost straight away just uncomment out the `$.mobile.changePage('#somePageId');` below.

N.B.  Remember if you are calling the pages in via ajax, since this is asynchronous you will need to make the changePage call inside the success function of the ajax call.

As for opening one of the dynamic pages directly after a full page refresh, this will never work as the dynamic page hasn't been added yet when you directly reference it with an anchor reference and hence it's Id isn't present in the DOM when you try and access it directly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>- jsFiddle demo by robschmuecker</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            //<![CDATA[ 
            $(window).load(function() {
                jsonData = {
                    "id": "introPage",
                        "element": "div",
                        "data": [{
                        "role": "page"
                    }],
                        "content": [{
                        "element": "div",
                            "data": [{
                            "role": "content"
                        }],
                            "content": [{
                            "id": "skip-intro",
                                "element": "a",
                                "href": "#mainPage",
                                "content": [{
                                "id": "introMovie",
                                    "element": "video",
                                    "classes": [
                                    "fullscreen"],
                                    "content": [{
                                    "element": "source",
                                        "type": "video/mp4",
                                        "src": "/src/assets/test.mp4"
                                }, {
                                    "element": "source",
                                        "type": "video/webm",
                                        "src": "/src/assets/test.webm"
                                }, {
                                    "element": "source",
                                        "type": "video/ogg",
                                        "src": "/src/assets/test.ogv"
                                },
                                    "Your browser does not support the video tag."]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                };

                function createPage(data) {
                    var page = createElement(data);
                    var id = page.attr('id');

                    $('body').append(page);
                    $('#' + id).trigger('create');
                };

                function createElement(template) {
                    var o;

                    o = $('<' + template.element + '/>');

                    if (template.id) {
                        o.attr("id", template.id);
                    }

                    if (template.href) {
                        o.attr("href", template.href);
                    };

                    if (template.src) {
                        o.attr("src", template.src);
                    };

                    if (template.type) {
                        o.attr("type", template.type);
                    };

                    if (template.classes) {
                        $.each(template.classes, function(i, item) {
                            o.addClass(item);
                        });
                    }

                    if (template.data) {
                        $.each(template.data, function(key, value) {
                            $.each(value, function(key, value) {
                                o.attr("data-" + key, value);
                            });
                        });
                    }

                    if (template.content) {
                        $.each(template.content, function(i, item) {
                            if (item.element) {
                                o.append(createElement(item));
                            } else {
                                o.append(item);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    return o;
                };
                createPage(jsonData);
                // Example of how to change page programatically.
                //$.mobile.changePage('#introPage');
            }); //]]>
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mainPage" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Page Title</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Page content goes here. <a href="#introPage">Click to load new page.</a>

                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer">
                    <h4>Page Footer</h4>

            </div>
            <!-- /footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/T5XEF/2/)

Comment: This is not correct, perhaps you do not understand. In your example you already have a default page. From there you have clicked to load the new page dynamically. What I am saying is there are no pages and my script creates them on the fly, after they have been created I need it to load either the first page or the hash

Comment: Please show how you create them dynamically?  You perhaps need to call the `$('#someNewPageId').trigger('create');` method on your pages and then load/change to the first one as per method above